# CSS presedence of selector over class

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

```
.formWrap input[type="text"] {
    font-size: 12px;    
}

.bigger {
    font-size: 14px
}

<div class="formWrap">
    <input type="text" class="bigger" />
</div>
```

Why does the above not make the text of the input field 14px?

When I am using the `input[type="text"]` selector how can I target a particular class that is a child of `formWrap`?

Is there a better method to give all my inputs a particular style then be able to make adjustments to certain inputs (hopefully based on a class)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first selector has higher specificity than the .bigger class.

To increase the specificity of the .bigger class, you could do this:

```
.formWrap input[type="text"]{
       font-size: 12px; 
}

.formWrap input[type="text"].bigger{
       font-size: 14px
}
```

OR (Not really recommended):

```
.bigger{
font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is [**Specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

Your first selector has higher *specificity* than your second selector, so its properties are prioritised.

`.formWrap input[type="text"]` contains a *class*, an *element* and *attribute* selector. As per the CSS selectors specification (linked above), this selector has a specificity of 21. `.bigger` on the other hand only has a *class* selector, and therefore only has a specificity of 10. 21 is greater than 10.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied. Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of selectors of different sorts.

In your case, an easy way to get your second selector to be prioritised over the first is by increasing this selector to have equal or higher specificity:

```css
input.bigger {}    /* 11 */
```

You can even repeat the same selector multiple times (as also noted in the specification):

```css
input.bigger.bigger {}               /* 21 */
```

*Note that if the specificity of both selectors are equal, the selector included later in your stylesheet will be the one prioritised.*

Comment: You probably explain why it has higher specificity (because there's a class + a child selector) vs. just a class selector.

Comment: Ok but how can I go about styling specific classes of input box that have already been styled by the general input styling?

Comment: Not quite. `.formWrap input[type="text"]` has a specificity of 0,0,2,1.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on specificity and how to calculate here. Something that takes a while to click when first starting to write CSS.

Calculating CSS Specificity Value
http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/